# C# MVC Google OAuth API 2 Sample Code Isnt Working

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

So I'm creating a c# mvc application, and trying to access some google API's (IE: Google Analytics).

I followed along with their tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

1st problem:

```
       public async Task IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
                AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (result.Credential != null)
            {
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                        ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC Sample"
                    });

                // YOUR CODE SHOULD BE HERE..
                // SAMPLE CODE:
                var list = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
                ViewBag.Message = "FILE COUNT IS: " + list.Items.Count();
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

is the function they say to use for the home controller.... but its erroring because you can't return a View() using just a Task, I changed it to

```
Task<ActionResult>
```

and it worked.

But the final problem, is that its infinitely redirecting.. im guessing because if credentials = null, its tries to redirect back?

This page isn’t working
accounts.google.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I've literally copied the sample code word for word and i can't for the life of me figure out why it's not returning credentials, or if something else is going wrong.

Comment: Feels to me like Google is redirecting you to IndexAsync() and that method in turn is making an authentication request to Google.. Hence the Too Many Redirects. Did you also implement your own callback controller?

Comment: I implemented the callback controller that was in the sample code tutorial. And yeah it is redirecting back to the callback, which in turn calls authenticate, if the credentials are null? At least that's what I'm guessing... I would have thought the sample code would just work

Comment: Just copying the code for the callback controller isn't enough. Maybe [this](https://www.sparkhound.com/blog/google-oauth-integration-using-an-mvc-asp-net-app-1) helps you understand.

Comment: Copied the entire tutorial; and its still returning Null for credentials. It has redirect URI but no credentials